# Why is Xcode trying to access 'cs193p.dyndns.org'

Tags: security, xcode4, ios5

Yesterday I installed Xcode 4.2 GM, today connected my iPhone (installed with iOS 5 GM) and clicked the "Use for Development" button in Organiser.

I was them confronted with this dialogue.

[image: Xcode attempting to connect to the host cs193p.dyndns.org]

The site http://cs193p.dyndns.org hosts some "Profiles", clicking on then download a profile and attempts to install it:

[image: Install profile]

(I clicked cancel)

This new System Preference then appears:

[image: System Preferences: Profiles]

I have know idea what this is or even if I should trust it.

Comment: looks legit to me. Can it be a preference pane for managing provisioning profiles for iOS5 devices?

Comment: Would Apple use a dyndns.org domain? If it's legit why not host it on an apple.com domain?

Comment: What IP did that resolve to for you? Was it your own IP, or an Apple IP, or...?

Comment: Resolved to 99.23.57.18, does look like an Apple IP: http://whois.arin.net/rest/nets;q=99.23.57.18?showDetails=true&showARIN=false&ext=netref2

Comment: Certainly has the appearance of either being ultra shady at worst or incredibly embarrassing.

Comment: cs193p is the designation code for the Stanford iOS developing course. Check it out on iTunes-U.

Answer (score 1):

cs193p is the Stanford course code for Paul Hegarty's iTunesU class.  Maybe you're using the helper ObjC class he offers for managing FRCs?  If so, check that code for references.